# Where is the device.mk file located for Android devices?

Tags: android, product, partitioning, super, partition

According to [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions/implement#upgrading-devices), the super partition can be split into multiple partitions. I'm specifically interested in splitting the super partition into multiple product and ODM partitions. My first goal is to locate the device.mk file. If anyone has experience splitting the super partition into multiple partitions or if there is a resource that you have found that goes into more detail, it would be extremely helpful. Thank you for reading.

Comment: hope this will help you https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#build-a-product

Comment: @AkibBagwan do you know where the device folder is? I can't locate it on my device within adb.